# How to count(*) of multiple tables, size and tablespace in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 working queries with correct output. 
First query gives list of table names and count,
second query gives list of table names, size in MB and tablespace name.

How to combine them to one query ?

Query 1:

```
select table_name
,to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(
dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
'select count(*) c from '||table_name))
,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
from user_tables 
where table_name like 'AUD_2012080%'
order by table_name desc;
```

Query 2:

```
select segment_name,blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB,tablespace_name 
from dba_segments 
where segment_name like 'AUD_2012080%' 
order by segment_name desc;
```

Output1:

```
TABLE_NAME                          COUNT
------------------------------ ----------
AUD_20120809                        27967 
AUD_20120808                        28269 
AUD_20120807                        29354 
AUD_20120806                        27155 
AUD_20120805                        18042 
AUD_20120804                        19033 
AUD_20120803                        24642 
AUD_20120802                        26760 
AUD_20120801                        25776
```

Output 2:

```
SEGMENT_NAME                 MB TABLESPACE_NAME              
-------------------- ---------- ------------------------------
AUD_20120809                 35 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120808                 35 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120807                 36 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120806                 34 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120805                 24 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120804                 24 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120803                 29 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120802                 32 WSS_BIG_I                      
AUD_20120801                 30 WSS_BIG_I
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
Table_name    count   owner    MB   Tablespace_name
AUD_20120801  25776   auditor  30   wss_big_i 
...
...
```

Comment: Is there any association between the tablespaces and the tablenames? If you can find one, like this tablename is associated with this tablename, I'd just do an Inner Join. That will give you a single result.

Answer (score 3):

As the segment is usually named like the table:

```
SELECT ut.table_name,
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype (dbms_xmlgen.getxml ('select count(*) c from ' ||ut.table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) row_count,
       db.blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB,
       db.tablespace_name 
FROM user_tables ut
  join dba_segments db on db.segment_name = ut.table_name
WHERE ut.table_name LIKE 'AUD_2012080%'
ORDER BY ut.table_name DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is:

```
SELECT ut.table_name
, NVL(extractvalue(xmltype (dbms_xmlgen.getxml ('select max(ID) x from ' || ut.table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/X'),0) maxID 
FROM all_tables ut
LEFT JOIN cols c ON c.TABLE_NAME = ut.TABLE_NAME
where ut.owner = 'OWNER'
AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'ID';
```