# SQL query, how to add count(*) column

Tags: sql, oracle, count, subquery

I have this query:

```
select segment_name,owner,blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB,tablespace_name
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'AUD_2%' and owner like 'AUDITOR'
order by 1 desc;

SEGMENT_NAME     OWNER              MB TABLESPACE_NAME
---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
AUD_201304       AUDITOR             7 WSS     
AUD_201303       AUDITOR            12 WSS     
AUD_201302       AUDITOR            11 WSS
```

how to add count(*) column ?

I guess a correlated subquery would do, but how exactly ?

Thanks !

sorry found code on stackoverflow, should better search next time. thanks

sorry, here the link to the solution:
[How to count(*) of multiple tables, size and tablespace in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822512/how-to-count-of-multiple-tables-size-and-tablespace-in-one-query?rq=1)

and here the code:

```
SELECT ut.table_name,
           to_number(extractvalue(xmltype (dbms_xmlgen.getxml ('select count(*) c from '         ||ut.table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) row_count,
       db.blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB,
       db.tablespace_name
FROM user_tables ut
  join dba_segments db on db.segment_name = ut.table_name
WHERE ut.table_name LIKE 'AUD_2%' and owner like 'AUDITOR'
ORDER BY ut.table_name DESC;
```

and here the output:

```
TABLE_NAME                      ROW_COUNT         MB TABLES
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ------
AUD_201304                          21067          7 WSS
AUD_201303                          43198         12 WSS
AUD_201302                          39046         11 WSS
AUD_201301                          44523         17 WSS
AUD_201212                          50580         15 WSS
AUD_201211                          49589         14 WSS
```

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: due to `dba_segments` in the query, I hazard a guess it's Oracle.

Comment: What exactly do you want to count?

Comment: If you found the solution, then at least have the decency to link to it and mark this question as answered (or closed as duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select 
        segment_name,
        owner,
        blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB,
        tablespace_name,
        (select num_rows from dba_tables where table_name=segment_name) TOTAL_ROWS
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'AUD_2%' and owner like 'AUDITOR'
order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: sorry, this does not work, gives column with number of tables, not the number of records in every table

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve @@ROW_COUNT at the end of your query

Comment: Not in Oracle you couldn't

Comment: I though it was a SQL Server question... So, what the Oracle counterpart of M$ @@ROW_COUNT?

Comment: @@ROW_COUNT is the equivalent of Oracle's SQL%ROWCOUNT.  My MSSQL is a bit rusty but I didn't think you could use @@ROW_COUNT in a query the way you suggest.  Certainly SQL%ROWCOUNT just returns the number of rows affected by the previous DML statement (that is # of rows updated, deleted, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to count.  But if you want to count the number of rows being returned, then use an analytic function:

```
select segment_name, owner, blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB, tablespace_name,
       count(*) over () as cnt
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'AUD_2%' and owner like 'AUDITOR'
order by 1 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

> "gives column with number of tables, not the number of records in every table "

Youy are mixing two differnet concepts.  data and metadata.

The query you have is queryiung the data dictionary to get some information about your tables as objects in the database.  This is metadata: data about the data.

Whereas a count of how many rows each table holds is just data.

You have two options.  The first is to join the DBA_TABLES view to your query and se;ect NUM_ROWS.  If your statistics are reasonably fresh and you only want an indicative figure this would probably suffice.

If you don't use statistics onthese tables or you want a highly accurate count you will need to use PL/SQL.

```
create or replace function tab_row_cnt ( tname in user_tables.table_Nmae%type)
return pls_integer
is
  n pls_integer;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||tname into n;
  return n;
end;
```

You can include this function in your query's projection.

```
select segment_name,owner,blocks*8192/1024/1024 as MB,tablespace_name
       , tab_row_cnt (segment_name) as row_count
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'AUD_2%' and owner like 'AUDITOR'
and segment_type = 'TABLE'
order by 1 desc;
```

Note that I added a test on SEGMENT_TYPE.  You will need to amend the function's logic if your tables are partitioned, or if you want to include index segments in the query.

Be aware that if your tables are large counting could take a long time and dramatically slow down your query.  Speed is another advantage of using the approximation offered by USER_TABLES.NUM_ROWS.